# phpEd not saving a file on server(apache) But file Save using SSH

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, apache2, phped

phpEd not saving a file on server(apache) using SFTP giving following error:

**"Could not write to remote File(var/www/erp/index.php)"**

When I open file (index.php) again it  is empty .Every File I open ,modify and save it gives the same error and on opening again it is empty .Any Clue Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your disk space. Usually these type of errors are generated by not having enough free space or improper privileges.
Use command df -h to check free space in linux!!